# Integrating jqGrid and JavaScriptMVC

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, javascriptmvc

Has anyone tried to integrate jqGrid and JavaScriptMVC, particularly using JMVC's model encapsulation to retrieve data instead of jqGrid?

It seems easy to add jqGrid as a plugin, but trying to incorporate it into the MVC model hasn't been easy at the outset.

Answer (score 0):

I setup a controller that has adds the grid to the view (usually to DIV) and provides functions for working with the grid such as "setData", "redraw", etc.

I keep a reference to the element that I assigned the grid to so I can do stuff such as:

```
this.gridEl.trigger('reloadGrid')
```

It took a bit of work to get it all working properly (i.e. had to do some stuff to get the sort icons to be set properly based on the column that was sorted, had to build a new 'localreader' object each time I wanted to set new data on the grid, etc).

So it's possible but will take some work especially if you want to control fetching data and giving it to the grid (the grid generally either wants to make server-side calls itself or it wants an array of data when you first build it, my situation was that I want to fetch data myself and then populate it, after the grid is built).